# grpc::ClientBidiReactor crashes when create ClientBidiReactor Continuously

Tags: c++, grpc

I have a function as follows:

```
  ErrorCode SendData(const char *data, size_t length)
  {
    auto stream = std::make_unique<Stream>(stub_.get(), client_id_, timeout_seconds_);
    return stream->SendMessage(data, length);
  }
```

and  Stream class:

```
class Stream : public grpc::ClientBidiReactor<SendBinaryDataRequest, SendBinaryDataResponse> {
   public:
    Stream(MessageTransfer::Stub *stub)
        : context_(), status_(grpc::Status::OK), done_(false), request_(), response_(), mu_(), cv_(), 
    {
      stub->async()->SendStreamBinaryDataWithAck(&context_, this);
      StartCall();
      std::cout << "new construtor:" << this << std::endl;
    }

    void OnWriteDone(bool ok) override
    {
      std::unique_lock<std::mutex> l(mu_);
      if (ok) {
        StartRead(&response_);
      }
    }

    void OnWritesDoneDone(bool) override
    {
      std::unique_lock<std::mutex> l(mu_);
      cv_.notify_one();
    }
    
    void OnReadDone(bool ok) override
    {
      std::unique_lock<std::mutex> l(mu_);
      if (ok) {
        cv_.notify_one();
      }
    }

    void OnDone(const grpc::Status &s) override
    {
      std::unique_lock<std::mutex> l(mu_);
      LOG("%p stream closed status:%d error:%s\n", this, s.error_code(), s.error_message().c_str());
      status_ = s;
      done_   = true;
      cv_.notify_one();
    }

    ErrorCode SendMessage(const char *data, size_t length)
    {
      std::unique_lock<std::mutex> l(mu_);

      if (done_) {
        return convertToErrorCode(status_);
      }

      request_.set_data(data, length);
      LOG("StartWrite %p\n", this);
      StartWrite(&request_);
      if(std::cv_status::timeout == cv_.wait_for(l, std::chrono::seconds(timeout_sec_))) {
        return ErrorCode_TIMEOUT;
      }
      if (done_) {
      return convertToErrorCode(status_);
      }
      return static_cast<ErrorCode>(response_.error_code());
    }
  }
```

when I use SendData to non-existent server, it will print "failed to connect to all addresses", this is right; However when I call SendData several times, it crashes:

pure virtual method called
terminate called without an active exception
Aborted (core dumped)

log:

```
new construtor:0x168dbc0
StartWrite 0x168dbc0
0x168dbc0 stream closed status:14 error:failed to connect to all addresses; last error: UNKNOWN: unix:/tmp/hs_message.sock: Connection refused
new construtor:0x168dbc0
StartWrite 0x168dbc0
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

It seems the ptr is same every time I make a stream. But I dont think it should be cause of the crash

[gdb info](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9k5BF.png)
[another gdb info](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nfbHM.png)
Can anyone help me? thanks

Comment: Your gdb trace is not helpful at all, it doesn't show any functions in the code posted above.

Comment: I think there is something wrong about grpc. May be I misuse some API

Comment: OnDone doesn't seem to be virtual in the parent class, yet you are overriding it. https://grpc.github.io/grpc/cpp/classgrpc_1_1_client_bidi_reactor.html#a51529f76deeda6416ce346291577ffa9

Comment: In OnWriteDone, I think you should notify the condition variable `if (ok)`, since that is called when StartWrite completes.

Comment: I expect to receive response after I write request, so I did not notify the condition variable in OnWriteDone

Comment: I need to override Ondone . Without it  I even dont know when the stream finishes.

Comment: Try putting a log in OnWriteDone when `ok = false`, you will probably get it false due to some issue. It says connection refused, so maybe you should check server address.

Comment: The server is not existed.  It is normal that the client cannot connect server. But it should not crash

Comment: You are trying to write even when you know connection isn't successful, I think there should be a way to first check the connection and only if it is successful, you write.

Comment: It seems in grpc c++, there is no such interface. I think the connectivity should be handled inside grpc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At last I find the program runs successfully after I added AddHold/RemoveHold
Codes like this:

```
class Stream : public grpc::ClientBidiReactor<SendBinaryDataRequest,SendBinaryDataResponse> {
public:
Stream(MessageTransfer::Stub *stub)
    : context_(), status_(grpc::Status::OK), done_(false), request_(), response_(), mu_(), cv_(), 
{
  stub->async()->SendStreamBinaryDataWithAck(&context_, this);
  AddHold()
  StartCall();
  std::cout << "new construtor:" << this << std::endl;
}

void OnWriteDone(bool ok) override
{
  std::unique_lock<std::mutex> l(mu_);
  if (ok) {
    StartRead(&response_);
  } else {
    RemoveHold();
  }
}

void OnWritesDoneDone(bool) override
{
  std::unique_lock<std::mutex> l(mu_);
  cv_.notify_one();
}

void OnReadDone(bool ok) override
{
  std::unique_lock<std::mutex> l(mu_);
  if (ok) {
    cv_.notify_one();
  } else {
    RemoveHold();
  }
}

void OnDone(const grpc::Status &s) override
{
  std::unique_lock<std::mutex> l(mu_);
  LOG("%p stream closed status:%d error:%s\n", this, s.error_code(), s.error_message().c_str());
  status_ = s;
  done_   = true;
  cv_.notify_one();
}

ErrorCode SendMessage(const char *data, size_t length)
{
  std::unique_lock<std::mutex> l(mu_);

  if (done_) {
    return convertToErrorCode(status_);
  }

  request_.set_data(data, length);
  LOG("StartWrite %p\n", this);
  StartWrite(&request_);
  if(std::cv_status::timeout == cv_.wait_for(l, std::chrono::seconds(timeout_sec_))) {
    return ErrorCode_TIMEOUT;
  }
  if (done_) {
  return convertToErrorCode(status_);
  }
  return static_cast<ErrorCode>(response_.error_code());
}
```

}

Comment: What is AddHold/RemoveHold? Why did you need to put them? Better to explain in your answer.

Comment: Actually, I don't quite understand. In the Grpc docs, It says "Holds are needed if (and only if) this stream has operations that take place on it after StartCall but from outside one of the reactions (OnReadDone, etc).". If someone could give some clear explanation, I would appreciate

Answer (score 0):

So, one immediate issue I noticed is that your reactor object `stream` can go out of scope and be deleted before the RPC is done.

https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/2892b24eabbb22b2344aba9c3ba84e529017b684/include/grpcpp/support/client_callback.h#L234
"The reactor may not be deleted until OnDone is called."

Consider the following events -

1. `SendData` is invoked, which invokes `SendMessage()` on a locally scoped `stream` object.
2. In `SendMessage()`, the `cv_.wait_for()` times out and returns.
3. `stream` object gets deleted.
4. At this point, the RPC fails and the gRPC library tries to invoke one of the callbacks, but the object is already deleted, leading to a SEGFAULT.

I think fixing this probably fixes the issue that you are seeing, but I haven't run this code myself.

I'll link to the examples just in case https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/master/examples/cpp/interceptors/client.cc.